# Substrings in bash

Tags: bash

I have strings that are long file names, like `a.b.c.d.e.output`. I want to extract the field `b`, which can be of a variable length.

How could I do this? I thought of splitting the string by `.` and taking `b` from that, but I'm not sure how to do that in `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [cut command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28Unix%29):

```
$ echo "a.b.c.d.e" | cut -d. -f2
b
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `read`, passing the file name with a here string:

```
IFS=. read a b rest <<< "$fname"
```

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail? What are IFS, read, and rest?

Comment: @goodcow `IFS` is the internal field separator in bash. So here `read` will read the first token before the `IFS` into `$a`, the second into `$b`, and the rest in `$rest`. It needs to be fixed here, since the general `IFS` doesn't contain `.` (usually something like `$'\t\n '`)

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case, you can do it in pure bash in two steps:

```
# This removes from $fn the shortest prefix matching the glob *.
dropfirst=${fn#*.}
# This removes the longest suffix matching the glob .*
component2=${dropfirst%%.*}
```

This can be generalized by changing dropfirst:

```
droptwo=${fn#*.*.}
dropthree=${fn#*.*.*.}
```

but note that `$fn` will just be passed through unaltered if there are not enough components.

In summary:

```
#   drop shortest prefix matching pattern
##  drop longest prefix matching pattern
%   drop shortest suffix matching pattern
%%  drop longest suffix matching pattern.
```

patterns can use any of the standard glob options (`*`, `?`, `[...]`), including extended patterns if you have `shopt -s extglob`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner. What makes this "pure bash" versus the other two answers?

Comment: @goodcow: looking at the others: the `read` solution is pure bash, since `read` is a builtin, but the solution with `cut` isn't, because `cut` is an external program and invoking it involves forking and execing a new process.